# How to restrict the event in jquery?

Tags: jquery

In my code i have restrict the default action of keydown event using "preventDefault()". And write the own code in my function like below

```
$("#myid").keydown(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    if (event.keyCode == 65) {
      alert("Hi Team")
    }
  }
})
```

Now,I need to restrict both default action of "ctrl+A" event and also to restrict my own code to display alert message also.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#myid").keydown(function(e){
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

   if (code == 65 && e.ctrlKey) //ctrl+A
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       //alert("Hi Team");
   }
});
```

To restrict Ctrl+A for whole document:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

   if (code == 65 && e.ctrlKey) //ctrl+A
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       //alert("Hi Team");
   }
});
```

Comment: My requirment is if press ctrl+A nothing should happen in the page,
Previously i have add some codes manually in "ctrl + A"  event. Now i need to restrict my manually added code and default function of "ctrl + A"

Comment: If you want restrict ctrl+A for whole page then instead of $("#myid") need to used $(document).keydown(). So this will prevent ctrl+A for whole document.

Comment: I just need to restrict only ctrl+A event using jquery.
I tried preventDefault() but it displays the alert message. alert message also have to restrict.

Comment: You need to remove alert from `ctrl+A if` condition as when ctrl+A is pressed it goes to that condition and it prevent event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass event object in function which is you used in code

```
$("#myid").keydown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   if(event.ctrlKey){
      if(event.keyCode == 65){
        alert("Hi Team")
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: My requirment is if press ctrl+A nothing should happen in the page,
Previously i have add some codes manually in "ctrl + A"  event. Now i need to restrict my manually added code and default function of "ctrl + A"

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$("#myid").off('keydown');
```

Comment: I just need to restrict only ctrl+A event using jquery.
I tried preventDefault() but it displays the alert message

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

**JavaScript**:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65){ // if ctrl + a
        e.preventDefault(); // stop selecting all
        alert("Hi team!"); 
    }
}
```

or **jQuery**:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Hi team!");
    }
});
```